# How can I permanently change css file in my website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to add a light/dark style function to my website. 
I wrote a code to change between two stylesheets when a button is clicked but whenever I go to a different route the style goes back to the regular one.

Javascript:

```
 function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
        document.getElementById('pageStyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/stylesheets/light.css" id="pageStyle">
    <body>
    <li><a id="navLinks" onclick="swapStyleSheet('/stylesheets/light.css')">Light Style!</a></li>
            <li><a id="navLinks" onclick="swapStyleSheet('/stylesheets/main.css')">Dark Style!</a></li>
    </body>
```

Comment: have you considered using session storage or cookies?

Comment: Using *just* JS - no, you need to expose a server endpoint that will also allow the modification. However, you can just save the user preferences client-side and when the user comes back restore those.

Comment: You can actually do this with pure JS, using `window.localStorage`. See my answer.

Comment: hey, never used cookies before so I am not familiar with it,

Answer (score 4):

#### You can do this with the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

This is similar to using cookies, but the data is stored in the browser rather than on the server. Supported by all modern browsers.

**JS:**

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pageStyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);

    window.localStorage.setItem("pageStyle", sheet);
}

window.onload = function() {
    swapStyleSheet(window.localStorage.getItem("pageStyle"));
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li><a id="navLinks" onclick="swapStyleSheet('/stylesheets/light.css')">Light Style!</a></li>
<li><a id="navLinks" onclick="swapStyleSheet('/stylesheets/main.css')">Dark Style!</a></li>
```